# how to find syntax error in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

if this is a duplicate please delete. 
I was just editing my .emacs file and after i had my changes done. I 
restarted emacs. But whet it comes up again it claims that the config
file has some errors. And i should start with "--debug-init" thats what 
i also have done. But it did not helped me to solve nor find the syntax error.
So is there a way to find the lines which have syntaxerror. Or even better if 
there would be something like a (e)lisp lint like you have for e.g xml, json, js 
and so on. Thanks in advance

#### Edit

Managed to get the dump:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable whitespace-mode)
  redisplay_internal\ \(C\ function\)()
  delete-process(#<process server-client-test>)
 Someunicodefoo" [("server") server-use-tcp server-auth-dir server-socket-dir generate-new-buffer " *temp*" funcall make-byte-code 0 "Someunicodefoo" vconcat vector [buffer-name kill-buffer] 2 "\n\n(fn)" insert-file-contents-literally expand-file-name looking-at "127\\.0\\.0\\.1:[0-9]+ \\([0-9]+\\)" comm process-attributes string-to-number match-string 1 t :other delete-process make-network-process :name "server-client-test" :family local :server nil :noquery :service] 14 "\n\n(fn)"])
  server-running-p("server")
  byte-code("Someunicodefoo" [load-file-name buffer-file-name recentf-menu-before user-emacs-directory recentf-save-file server-name add-to-list load-path file-name-directory "../packages" tool-bar-mode 0 load "ergoemacs-keybindings/ergoemacs-mode" ergoemacs-mode 1 "init_load_packages" "init_version" "init_functions" "init_settings" "init_aliases" "init_abbrevs-lisp-mode" "init_keybinding" "init_mouse" "init_clean_menus" require recentf "Close" ".recentf" recentf-mode server server-running-p t server-start] 4)
  load("/home/dirk/.emacs.d/ergoemacs_1.9.3.1/site-lisp/../ergoemacs/init")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-842275> nil "/home/dirk/.emacs.d/ergoemacs_1.9.3.1/site-lisp/site-start.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1432
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/dirk/.emacs.d/ergoemacs_1.9.3.1/site-lisp/site-start.el" "/home/dirk/.emacs.d/ergoemacs_1.9.3.1/site-lisp/site-start.el" nil nil)
  load("/home/dirk/.emacs.d/ergoemacs_1.9.3.1/site-lisp/site-start.el" nil nil t)
  load-file("~/.emacs.d/ergoemacs_1.9.3.1/site-lisp/site-start.el")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/dirk/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 2883
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/dirk/.emacs" "/home/dirk/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Comment: What is the error? If you don't tell us, we can't help you. Did you get a stack trace when you ran `emacs --debug-init`? If so, paste that into your question as well.

Comment: @phils Unfotunally i dont get a backtrace when i start with --debug-init. It just says "Package assoc" is obsolete. On the other hand if i start normaly it gives me the "start with --debug-init" message

Comment: There are a lot of unknowns in that stack trace, but try inserting `(require 'whitespace)` into your init file ahead of the ergoemacs bits. Without knowing what that other code is actually doing, this might be the simplest way to get past the error (the `whitespace` library defines the `whitespace-mode` variable).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do it is to open the file and mark the first half of it and apply `eval-region`. If an error is reported, mark half of it and repeat. If an error isn't reported, apply it to the other half.

This way you could narrow down the problem and once you have found it you can hopefully figure out the problem.

<strike>Another technique I use to find incorrect parentheses is to add an extra parenthesis to the beginning and end of the file, respectively and run <kbd>C-M-f</kbd> and <kbd>C-M-b</kbd> from the beginning and end, respectively. If there are incorrect parentheses, they will match the newly added ones, and the point will move to the incorrect ones.</strike>

*EDIT:* You can use <kbd>M-x check-parens</kbd> to check for unmatched parentheses.

Comment: I would suggest `M-x check-parens` in place of the manual method described.

Comment: @phils thanks for the advice the "M-x check-parens" did it for me... but you did not post it as answer. Do you want to post it as answer so i can click this as solved?

Comment: @phils, posting this as a separate answer would be fine with me, after all, you came up with it in the first place.

Comment: Go ahead and accept this answer, PolymathMonkey. It was Lindydancer's suggestion to check for unbalanced parentheses which solved the issue for you, rather than the particular method by which you did so.

Answer (score 5):

For "lint"-like checking, there's `elint.el`, but more importantly, there's the byte-compiler: `M-x byte-compile-file RET` lets you byte-compile a file and will give you all kinds of warnings about syntax and style.

But your backtrace indicates that the problem is probably not one of syntax.  Most like there's a `whitespace-mode` that appears somewhere in a *menu* (i.e. in an `:enable` property of a menu entry), and that signals an error because the `whitespace-mode` variable happens not to be defined yet.  So as Phils suggests, loading `whitespace` would probably work around the problem.